# React Native landscape mode for only one page

Tags: react-native

Is it possible in react native to have the app run in portrait mode but have one page run in landscape mode?  I know in xcode you have to select portrait or landscape at the beginning so I am a little confused as to how to make all pages in the app portrait except one.

Comment: Check https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a very well built package : [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation)

The only downside is that you'll need to specify in every scene of your app the orientation with :

`Orientation.lockToPortrait();`

or

`Orientation.lockToLandscape();`

Comment: I've been using this too, but can't get it to work anymore in RN0.44 :'(

Comment: In react navigation v6 u can do this:

      <AppStack.Screen
        name="VehiclesDetailsAuction"
        component={VehiclesDetailsAuction}
        options={{ orientation: 'portrait' }}
      />
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="VehicleImageView"
        component={VehicleImageView}
        options={{ orientation: 'all' }}
      />

Answer (score 15):

In react navigation v6 you can do this:

```
  <AppStack.Screen
    name="VehiclesDetailsAuction"
    component={VehiclesDetailsAuction}
    options={{ orientation: 'portrait' }}
  />
  <AppStack.Screen
    name="VehicleImageView"
    component={VehicleImageView}
    options={{ orientation: 'all' }}
  />
```

Comment: This is the best solution I have found after searching for hours. I'm working on a streaming app that has a full screen video player, and this works perfectly for that scenario. No need to use any third party library anymore,

Comment: Seems then we have to put orientation for each specific screen, not great.

Answer (score 4):

I Hope this answer will help you

Project->_text->android->app->src->main->AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.reactnativeweb">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**only this one line add on your project in your**

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: What about IOS?

Comment: Xcode there is an option 
general->deployemnt info-> device orientation
device orientation checkbox you can choose as per need
landspace left
landspace right

Answer (score 1):

if you are using expo try this package: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation