# How to make a specific screen to appear in landscape mode (for example play video) whereas others are locked in portrait mode in react native?

Tags: react-native, device-orientation

Here is the code snippet that I have used, but it is not working. It is displaying in portrait mode only

This is a code which I have used for running a video

```
let w = useWindowDimensions().width;
let h = useWindowDimensions().height;

export default function VideoPlayer() {
    let link = "mov.mp4";
    const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState('landscape');
    useEffect(() => {
        if(w > h)
        {
           setOrientation('landscape')
        }else{
           setOrientation('portrait')
        }
     }, [])
    
     return (
           <Video source={{ uri: link }}
                  style={{ width: w, height: h,}}
                  controls={true}
                  playInBackground={false}
                  pictureInPicture
                  resizeMode='contain'
                  fullscreenOrientation={orientation}
                  fullscreen={true}
             />
        );
}
```

Comment: Check it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235342/react-native-landscape-mode-for-only-one-page

Comment: If the landscape orientation is set from android manifest file then all the screens will be working for landscape only. So this will not work. 
Locking the orientation from react native code is not working. I have tried it.